# JS construction function returns keys not in quotation mark

Tags: javascript, string, constructor, this

so my question is this: when creating an instance with JS construction functions, the mentioned instance returns key-property pairs that are not inside quotation marks. like instead of "key" : "value" returns key : value

this is my code:

```js
const watchList = [{
  "Title": "Inception",
  "imdbRating": "8.8"
}]


const filteredList = [];

function Movie(_Title, _imdbRating) {
  this.title = _Title;
  this.rating = _imdbRating;
}

let var1 = watchList
  .map(function(element) {
    return new Movie(element["Title"], element['imdbRating'])
  })
  .filter(function(elem) {
    return parseInt(elem.rating, 10) >= 8.0
  })


filteredList.push(var1)

console.log(filteredList);
```

//should return "Title" but return Title

So sorry if it's a noob-like question, couldn't find the answer anywhere!

Comment: Keys/values in JSON don't contain quotes usually. See [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)/[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: I've converted your code to a runnable snippet. I'm not seeing **Title** on it's own...

Comment: On another note, you should probably use `parseFloat`. `parseInt` will round down to the nearest integer value

Comment: @BladeMight Try running this in your console `JSON.stringify({thing : 1})`

Comment: @LeeTaylor And? I mean in raw format there isn't quotes, but in string format there is, I know that.

Comment: @BladeMight then that's not JSON. JSON is the **string** representation of a Javascript object...

Comment: @LeeTaylor Oh, I see thats what I didn't know.

Comment: @BladeMight Thanks Guys for all you help, guess the problem lies in JSON.

Comment: In JavaScript code: `{ Title: "Inception" }`, `{ "Title": "Inception" }` and `{ ["Title"]: "Inception" }` all have a key called `Title`. **However**, `{ "\"Title\"": "Inception" }`, `{ '"Title"': "Inception" }`, and `{ ["\"Title\""]: "Inception" }` all have a key called `"Title"`.